# Jmeter web application performance testing doubts?

Tags: node.js, web-applications, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I am new to jmeter and have a couple of doubt about web application performance testing.

1. Is it necessary to load all embedded resource in jmeter for performance testing ?
2. I have written a Jmeter script that exercise all REST apis. Is this enough to find the application performance at the server side ?
3. How Ramp up time affects the Performance test ?
4. For how much time the test needs to be executed, to get an accurate performance report ?
5. Load Generation configuration - Generating load from machines attached to application cluster / from different LAN ?

Comment: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/ might be better suited for this type of questions.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly find my view on the questions below:

1. I believe that load test needs to be as much realistic as possible so representing real browser behavior is a must. Real browsers download embedded resources like scripts, images and styles, moreover, they use a concurrent thread pool of 2 - 8 threads to do this in parallel. So you need to configure JMeter similarly. However real browsers download these assets only once, on subsequent requests they return embedded resources from cache. So make sure that you configure JMeter to:

   - download embedded resources
   - use concurrent pool for it
   - add [HTTP Cache Manager](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cache-manager) to your test plan
2. It should be enough from functional point of view as usually static content is being served separately. However see point 1, if you have possibility to simulate real user behavior - go for it
3. It is better to have reasonable ramp-up and ramp-down periods so the load could increment gradually so both server and load generator sides won't experience peak stress loads (unless it is your test case). See [the bit on ramp-up from JMeter documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#thread_group)

> Ramp-up needs to be long enough to avoid too large a work-load at the start of a test, and short enough that the last threads start running before the first ones finish (unless one wants that to happen).
>
> Start with Ramp-up = number of threads and adjust up or down as needed.
>
> By default, the thread group is configured to loop once through its elements.

4. Usually  peak load follows general [Pareto principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle),  during "peak" periods application served 80% of requests during 1-2 hours time frame and remaining 20% of requests were more or less equally distributed between remaining 20 hours in a day. So it should be enough to test your application providing anticipated peak load for a couple of hours. Again if time allows I would recommend to go for [Soak testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soak_testing) to see if there are any memory leaks and for [Stress testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_testing) to determine application load boundaries and whether it recovers from stress load or not
5. Theoretically application shouldn't care regarding requests source (unless it uses different logic to handle requests from i.e. different geo regions). One thing is obvious: don't run load generator and application under test on the same machine. If one JMeter instance cannot create enough load to implement test scenario - go for [distributed testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)

Comment: Do i need to add a delay between two request?

Comment: There are 2 ways of simulating the load:

1. Emulating N simultaneous real users. In this case it would be better to add realistic think times between requests. 
2. Emulating N requests per second. In that case delay is not required, just add [Constant Throughput Timer](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) to ensure that JMeter is sending  requests at desired rate. 

Personally I would rather go for 1st option

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add some more perspective:

**Question 1 & 2:**

The Pareto principle can be applied here also - meaning, that it takes a lot of effort to properly simulate reality, downloading all resources used by a browser to render a page and to give the proper 'weights' to different URLs, simulating user behaviour accurately. This is where many load tests fail, because simulating reality accurately is very, very hard. As the previous response mentions, most static content is often served via CDNs or similar anyway, and what you really want to test is usually your own system's capability to handle traffic.

Considering the above, I would say that if you spend 20% of effort setting up a load test that tests your REST API, you will get 80% of the results you want. If you on the other hand go for a completely realistic test, you will spend another 80% of effort for only 20% more results. The effect of this is that in many cases it is better to go for the simpler test, that does *not* simulate reality accurately. It gives you the most return on your invested time.

**Question 3:** Agree fully with previous response here. Ramp up slowly, unless your specific use case sees very sudden traffic peaks (like if you're an online auction service or ticket sales or similar). Can also be a good idea to configure your test so it spends some time on a "plateau" after ramping up to peak load, and not just stopping the load test once you reach the peak.

**Question 4:** I would say you need to run the load test long enough to produce stable, statistically significant results. This can be 5 minutes or 5 hours depending on your scenario, but half an hour is probably a good minimum time to aim for in mostly all cases. The test duration should not be dependent on how long your site tends to experience peak load in real life though - not unless you're doing some kind of soak test.

**Question 5:** Traffic origin is sometimes worth thinking about, as different source locations lead to different network delay between (simulated) clients and server, which affects transaction rates. If you run a load test with 1,000 VUs on a system located in New York, and generate the traffic from Australia, you will not get a lot of transactions per second due to the high network delay. If you run the same test using a load generator in New York instead, your transaction rate will be a *lot* higher because the network delay is so much lower. Of course, you can always add more concurrent clients/VUs/connections and get the same transaction rate on a high-delay network link that you would on a low-delay link, but at the cost of forcing the server to keep a lot more (TCP) connection state, using more file descriptors and buffer memory. I.e. might not be a very realistic scenario.